# New install of 14.04 with wired connection. getting error "Disconnected - you are now offline"

Tags: networking, ethernet

Pretty much the title. Feeling really lost.

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:97:a6:97  
          inet6 addr: fe80::76d4:35ff:fe97:a697/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:78 (78.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A 2 -Fe Ethernet`

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Do the lights on the Ethernet port(s) indicate a working Ethernet connection? Please run `lspci -nnk | grep -A 2 -Fe Ethernet` and `ifconfig` and post their output.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: What happens if you do a "Try Ubuntu"? Do you get disconnected as well?  Are you Using WiFi or cable? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: @Fabby Sorry for the delayed response. I have a wired connection. It seems that it tries to connect and then shows the message disconnected. But then immediately tries to reconnect. I also cannot view the connection information as it is grayed out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do any of the lights go on (on the router or on the PC) when you plug/unplug the cable as @DavidFoerster asked?  If not, did you try another cable?  If that doesn't change anything, please provide the output to `ethtool eth0` before and after connecting?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for cleaning up my post. I saw that you had "remove loop interface" at the top of the fixed post. I'm a little unsure as to what that means. Again, thanks for all the help.